# PDO Login doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So a couple days ago i had trouble creating a login, one person on that thread recommended me using prepared statements instead.

So I started looking up prepared statements using PDO and I've managed to create the register script with it. However, my login redirects me back to index.php everytime.

file1.php:

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ismsite', 'db_username', 'db_password'); //this works
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
$result->bindParam(':username', $username);
$result->bindParam(':password', $password);
$result->execute();
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($row > 0) {
    session_start();
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id']; // Initializing Session
            $_SESSION['voornaam'] = $row['Voornaam']; // Initializing Session
            $_SESSION['achternaam'] = $row['Achternaam'];
            $_SESSION['adres'] = $row['adres'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
}
header("location: profile.php");
exit();
?>
```

On profile.php i have a small bit of code checking if the session with user_id exists. if it doesn't you'll be reverted back to index.php. This would indicate my userid session not being set while i am setting it right there. Either selecting doesn't work the same way as inserting or i have a stupid error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It's failed since you start the session in that conditional block.

Comment: Okey i've fixed it myself.i had to change FETCH_NUM to FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: Start by dropping the redirect, var_dump the content returned in `$row` and work from there. I'd suggest doing `if ($row)` as well, since it'll be an array if successful (and `FETCH_NUM` returns an indexed array - from how you're using `$row` afterwards, I think you want `FETCH_ASSOC` as you fetch mode.

Comment: either post an answer and accpet it, or delete the question.

Comment: MatsLindh, yea i checked through my old code and found FETCH_ASSOC and changed it to FETCH_NUM. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why this if($row > 0) { its an array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i made the mistake of using FETCH_NUM instead of using FETCH_ASSOC in:

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

used to be

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```